# Uncaught TypeError: r[o].hasOwnProperty is not a function when trying to use a Static Resource

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, static-resources

I'm currently working on a Lightning Component that needs a third party library when the library is loaded I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: r[o].hasOwnProperty is not a function
throws at /resource/1483607349000/CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:3:5027 TypeError: r[o].hasOwnProperty is not a function
   at Function.t.widget.extend (CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:3)
   at Function.t.widget.extend (CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:3)
   at Function.t.widget.extend (CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:3)
   at Function.t.widget.extend (CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:3)
   at Function.t.widget (CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:3)
   at CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:7
   at CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:3
   at Object.<anonymous> (CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:3)
   at $globalEvalIIFE$ (CloudRebelTest__styleguidejs:30)
   at value (safeEval.html:78)
a @ aura_prod.js:723
(anonymous) @ aura_prod.js:723
```

Is there a way to work around it and to know why hasOwnProperty is not recognized as a function ?

Comment: Can you name the third party library you're using? Is it JavaScript strict mode compliant?

Comment: It's a library used by a client so I can't name it unfortunately, it's minified and I don't have access to the full version. Is there big changes depending on the compliance to the strict mode ?

Comment: Ok. And yes, [Salesforce has introduced Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html). One of the basic requirements in it is that, the external JS libraries you're using should be JavaScript strict mode compliant.

Comment: @SE_User even when the LockerService is disabled I get the same problem, as for the library it contains jQuery-UI and I think the problem is coming from it